# DropDownListFor using ViewBag of SelectListItems

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Controller for partial view

```
    public ActionResult _AddRedirect()
{
    var domains = (from d in DB.Tokens
                    orderby d.Domain
                    select d).Distinct().Select(d => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = d.Domain,
                        Text = d.Domain

                    });
    ViewBag.DomainList = domains.AsEnumerable();

    return PartialView();
}
```

Snippet of partial view for drop down list

```
        <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
         model => model.Domain,
         ViewBag.DomainList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>),
         new {@class="form-control dropdown"}
     )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

Calling the partial view from Index.cshtml

```
    @Html.Action("_AddRedirect", new ViewDataDictionary())
```

No compile errors with this, but when the page loads, I get this exception:

> System.Web.HttpException occurred
>         HResult=0x80004005
>         Message=Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
>         Source=System.Web.Mvc
>         StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, Object routeValues)
>          at ASP._Page_Views_Admin_Index_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\lpjobray\source\repos\Windows-MidTier\WMTRedirectMgr\WMTRedirectMgr\Views\Admin\Index.cshtml:line 7
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

```
Inner Exception 1:
HttpParseException: "class" is a reserved word and cannot be used in implicit expressions.  An explicit expression ("@()") must be used.
```

If I change Html.DropDownListFor to add the list items statically with new SelectListItem, everything renders fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant `)` after `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. It's closing the `DropDownListFor` without the object intended for `htmlAttributes` parameter. Change it to:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Domain,
        ViewBag.DomainList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
        new {@class="form-control dropdown"}
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a syntax error defining the htmlAttributes bit.  Changing to this resolved the problem.

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
        model => model.Domain,
        ViewBag.DomainList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Domain, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: you don't need `htmlAttributes:`

Comment: [Named arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) are not required here. `DropDownListFor` helper is using the intended overload. The issue you were facing is explained in my answer.

Comment: I don't know, when I changed it from what it was in my original post, it started working...

Comment: @JOb801 your original post has an extra closing bracket which caused the error. `ViewBag.DomainList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>),` <----This.. The answer you have posted doesn't. If you remove `htmlAttributes:` part also, your `DropDownListFor` will work just fine. The error was due to `new {@class="form-control dropdown"}` being outside of the `DropDownListFor()`